# Running SpinRite on SAN attached LUN with NTFS corruption

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage-area-network, ntfs, corruption

Got a customer that has an issue with NTFS corruption that is popping up on SAN attached storage.  The LUN is RAID-10 (4:1 spindle ratio).  The machines are Windows Server 2003 (64-bit), and they are in the planning stages to migrate to Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit).

The manufacture of the SAN (who shall remain nameless) is at a loss for what to do (or why they are occurring), and Microsoft Support has said to go to backups. (Not an easy thing, the backup method is BLOCK-LEVEL, not FILE-LEVEL.  Any corruption on the drive is copied into the backup).

I know it's a long shot, but would it be worthwhile to run SpinRite on the LUN?

Comment: What transport protocol are they using (i.e. FC/FCoE, iSCSI etc.)? and what additional software and/or drivers are in place?

Comment: I know it's Fibre Channel.  Not sure about additional software and/or drivers.

Comment: FC SANs, especially when configured using Server 2003, are notoriously picky about using a validated stack of components. This means ensuring that your OS, drivers, MPIO software and HBA firmware are all in a supported chain of levels - ensure you're using a supported set. Also be aware that 2003 and 2008 deal with FC a fair bit differently and require changes on most/many SAN arrays during migration plus you don't want one LUN being shared by BOTH 2003 and 2008 at the same time if you can avoid it.

Comment: I Don't think spinrite would help.  If spinrite found errors at what level would they be occurring? Fibre channel presents as a physical drive attached to the system but in reality is a networked drive with a bunch of different devices in the way.  Are you trying to move the lun owner between hosts or is the corruption occurring during copy between luns?